# google sheet punch card

Tags: google-sheets, index-match

I am trying to create a conditional color change on a google sheet.

I don't know how to connect the dots.
I feel I need an 'indirect' function.  Please see attached file.  I would like the corresponding period to change color if it matches on the Data sheet.  On the 'User' Sheet there is a reference to the unique id in cells A4, E4, I4, M4, Q4 etc.  I was thinking of a `vlookup`, but have been playing with `index(match(indirect(...`

I tried to transpose the data under Roster1 for an easier Index Match

```
'=Transpose(filter(Data!$D$2:$D$11,Data!$A$2:$A$11=A6))'
```

I am expecting on the User Sheet the color of the matching period to change to red if it is found on the data sheet linked to the unique ID. [Sheet Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gvr7FuQ35M9zMeh5CHZywhVBG8kgWVNLdFcbOSvFavg/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below formula to conditional formatting rule-

```
=XMATCH(B6,FILTER(INDIRECT("Data!D:D"),INDIRECT("Data!A:A")=$A$4))
```

In your google-sheet, see tab ***harun24hr***.

[image]

Comment: thats it!  Thank you!  'XMatch' Brilliant

Comment: it seems to break on the third person. =MATCH(J6, FILTER(INDIRECT("Data!D:D"),INDIRECT("Data!A:A")=$I$4))

Comment: You were using `match` function instead of `xmatch` for the third person which is resulting in the erroneous output...

Comment: SOLVED...Thank you Harun24hr and thank you rockinfreakshow for pointing out how I always miss details!